# Python unittest not running

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7

Windows XP
Python 2.7

I'm following the code in Beginning Python book and have two files in a folder called testing.
I'm trying to get it to fail but it wont even run the tests.The first file my_math.py is just a dummy product function

```
def product(x, y):
    pass
```

The second is the test test_my_math.py

```
import unittest, my_math

class ProductTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def testIntegers(self):
        for x in xrange(-10, 10):
            for y in xrange(-10, 10):
                p = my_math.product(x, y)
                self.failUnless(p == x*y, 'Integer multiplication failed')

    def testFloats(self):
        for x in xrange(-10, 10):
            for y in xrange(-10, 10):
                x = x/10.0
                y = y/10.0
                p = my_math.product(x, y)
                self.failUnless(p == x*y, 'Float multiplicaton failed')

    if __name__ == '__main__': unittest.main()
```

When I run the test in the command line

```
C:\Python27\Example_Programs\testing>python test_my_math.py

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK

C:\Python27\Example_Programs\testing>
```

Comment: Presumably the indentation of the `if __name__` test is a posting error?

Comment: No, it's not. That's the exact output from having this indented that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then unindent that `if` to the top level (no spaces before it).  Otherwise it is part of the code block of the `class` definition and will be executed before the class is finished (thus no unit tests have been created at this point).

Comment: Thanks The indented If was causing it not to run. Another Homer moment

Answer (score 0):

The upper reason that Mr. Alfe answered is also correct
Other reason might be following

```
def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        browser=self.browser
        browser.get("http://google.com")
```

It might be possible that you have to probably define this code till browser.get method in **setUp()** function
The rest of the code will be defined in the next segment of the second function

& here **setUp()** function name is mandatory , otherwise it causes an error